# Configuring vim to open new windows on Windows 7

Tags: vim

On my old Windows XP laptop, which I set up about 2 years ago, I have vim71 installed.  I renamed vim.exe to vi.exe.  And when I invoke vi with a file name from a Windows Command Prompt, vi opens up the file in a new window.  (By "new window", I mean a window in the Microsoft Windows sense, not in the vi sense.)  The Command Prompt is then available to accept a new command.

I am now trying to configure vim similarly on a new Windows 7 laptop.  I installed vim72 (the latest version), and I renamed vim.exe to vi.exe.  Now, when I invoke vi with a file name from a Windows Command Prompt, vi opens the file inside the Command Prompt window (instead of opening up a new Microsoft Windows window).

How can I get vi to open up files in a new Microsoft Windows window?  (Is this a difference between vim71 and vim72, or a difference between vim on XP and vim on Windows 7, or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run `gvim.exe` instead of `vim.exe`.

`gvim.exe` launches the GUI version of Vim, whereas `vim.exe` just runs inside a command-prompt window (as you've discovered). I believe it's been this way for at least the last several versions.

Instead of renaming `gvim.exe` to `vi.exe`, consider using an alias or a batch file to call the executable under its existing name. The Windows version of Vim includes several other programs that expect the GUI version of Vim to be called `gvim.exe`, so changing the name is likely to break something.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.  I copied (not moved) gvim.exe to vi.exe, and it's working great.  Thanks!